# No me imprime la fecha anterior en una clase de fecha en PYTHON

Tags: python, poo, date

Ayuda bandamax, no me imprime el día anterior de una fecha añadida desde teclado, me marca error y no imprime. No encuentro el problema.

```py
import datetime as dt

class Fecha:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fecha = "1-1-1900"
        self.YR = 0
        self.DS = 0
        self.MONT = 0

    '''GETTERS'''

    def getFecha(self):
        return self.fecha
    
    def getDS(self):
        return self.DS

    def getMONT(self):
        return self.MONT

    def getYR(self):
        return self.YR

    '''SETTERS'''

    def setFecha(self, fecha):
        self.fecha = fecha

    def setDS(self, DS):
        self.DS = DS

    def setMONT(self, MONT):
        self.MONT = MONT

    def setYR(self, YR):
        self.YR = YR

    '''METODOS'''

    def leer(self):
        DS = int(input("Ingrese  un dia  (1 - 31): "))
        MONT = int(input("Ingrese  un mes  (1 - 12)  "))
        YR = int(input("Ingrese un año (1900 - 2050): "))
        self.setDS(DS)
        self.setMONT(MONT)
        self.setYR(YR)
        fecha = dt.datetime(self.getYR(), self.getMONT(), self.getDS())
        fecha1 = fecha.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
        self.setFecha(fecha1)

    def diaAnterior(self):
        FecA = self.getFecha()
        FecA2=dt.datetime.strptime(f"",{FecA},"%d-%m-%Y")
        TotD = FecA2.date() - dt.timedelta(days=1)
        print("El dia anterior es",TotD)

fechas = Fecha()
fechas.leer()
print(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente el problema está en esta línea mal formateada:

```
FecA2=dt.datetime.strptime(f"",{FecA},"%d-%m-%Y")
```

Debe ser:

```
FecA2=dt.datetime.strptime(FecA,"%d-%m-%Y")
```

Con ese arreglo ya no da error, pero tampoco imprime nada, esto es porque NO estas llamando al método que imprime el valor.
Entonces, como última línea de todo el programa, escribe:

```
fechas.diaAnterior()
```